# Convert column Ageday to blank value instead of zero

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

.DischargeDate)
              ELSE ''
        END AS 'AgeDay'

Please help me that in `ageday` column I should be able to see empty string rather than null or o but now I'm seeing 0

Comment: Don't put "urgent" in your title please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT

      Mrn.PrefixMedicalRecordNumber as 'Key' 
    ,DATEDIFF(YY,Him.Birthdate,Bar.DischargeDate) as 'Age'
    ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YY,Him.Birthdate,Bar.DischargeDate) < 1
     THEN ISNULL(NULLIF(CAST(DATEDIFF(d,Him.Birthdate,Bar.DischargeDate) AS VARCHAR(10)) , 0) , '')
     ELSE''
     END as 'AgeDay'
```

Comment: Might be worth explaining to the OP why this works, seems they aren't aware of data type precedence. :)

Comment: Thank you M. Ali , I Appreciate your Expertise